# error running windows certification toolkit version 2.2

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I recently updated the windows certification toolkit to version 2.2 and ever since the update I have been unable to run the toolkit against any of my windows store applications.

When I create packages within visual studio and run the toolkit as part of the wizard I get the following error:

the {0} cannot continue testing since the specified windows store app was not found.  Please verify that the packagefullname is correct.

When I run the toolkit as a stand-alone application, I select 'windows store app' and it never finds any of my applications.

Anyone have ideas or suggestions that will help me from pulling out the rest of my hair?

Comment: Same problem here. Anyone a hint or idea? I've this problem when running from within visual studio.

Comment: I had some communication from Microsoft and they recommended that I reinstall the OS, visual studio, ...

Comment: Lol that is also a solution :p I  did same thing and it works. But it looks a little oversized as a workaround for me ;-/ But still it also helped here.